# How to add a new index signature to a class declaration from file.d.ts in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have a class like the following:

```
// some npm module
export class User {
  fname: string;
  lname: string;
}
```

But I cannot update the declaration of this class from my project root because it is an npm module.
I want to add a new index signature to this class but am unable to do so!
I tried the following code, but it doesn't work!

```
// file.d.ts
export declare class User {
  customProperty: any;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to export the `declaration`, all you need to in your `file.d.ts` is to do something like this,I'll use `axios` as an example here:

```
declare module "axios" {
  interface AxiosRequestConfig {
    customProperty: "some-type";
  }
  interface AxiosInstance {
    request<T = any>(config: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<T>;
    get<T = any>(url: string, config?: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<T>;
    delete<T = any>(url: string, config?: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<T>;
    head<T = any>(url: string, config?: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<T>;
    options<T = any>(url: string, config?: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<T>;
    post<T = any>(url: string, data?: any, config?: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<T>;
    put<T = any>(url: string, data?: any, config?: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<T>;
    patch<T = any>(url: string, data?: any, config?: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<T>;
  }
}
```

for more information read module augmentation in typescript docs: [here is the link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much :)

Comment: @SaifAliKhan Cheers bro, if it was helpful, try to add an upVote to the answer